# 'ipkg search xxx' always returns no answer

Tags: search, ipkg

On a Synology NAS (uses a 'home grown' *nix variant (possibly based on Debian?)) I have installed ipkg package manager.  When I try a command like

```
ipkg search shred
```

or

```
ipkg search *shred*
```

it returns only the single line:

```
Successfully terminated
```

without any package name.

I specifically used shred in my example as I know that shred exists for my platform and is part of the coreutils package (and so should return that answer.)

What is going wrong?  Is this a bug, an error in my syntax or possibly something else?

Edit -

I found the answer - filename needed to be enclosed in single quotes like

```
ipkg search '*shred*'
```

This returns the correct answer - coretutils.

I also found that Pavel is correct, it only returns info on *installed* packages, which is not what I needed.

How would I go about finding what pkg to install if I need a given program/util that is part of a larger collection but don't know what package contains it?

(is that permitted or should I start another question?)

Comment: Why do you assume it should return that answer if there's no package called shred but instead it's part of coreutils?

Comment: The description of ipkg search states that it should find files within packages.  From `ipkg --help`: `search <file|regexp>  Search for a package providing <file>`    I take this to mean for a given filename, return the package containing it.  To be sure however, `ipkg search coreutils` also returns nothing.

Comment: Sorry, new to Stack - meant to call out @PavelŠimerda in my previous comment.

Comment: I'm getting your comments even without the tag.

Comment: Assuming `ipkg` behaves closely like `opkg` (on OpenWrt): `opkg search xyzzy` will return which installed package has the file `xyzzy`. After updating the packages information using `opkg update` you can do `opkg find *shred*` and this returns `coreutils-shred`...

Comment: @yeti: If you have any information on files of packages that are not installed, please edit my answer or add comments so I can edit myself.

Comment: I have not seen a debian-like `apt-file` command needing an own files-to-packagename database in OpenWrt. For systems aiming to have a small footprint this is contra productive. but maybe I just do not know it's name in OpenWrt?

Comment: @yeti: I wasn't aware there's such a tool with its own database in Debian. It has to be generated from the package files themselves. In RPM based distributions I don't know anything like that either.

Comment: Look at `ftp://ftp.debian.org/debian/dists/stable/` ... the file-to-packagenames indices are the files named `Contents-$ARCHITECTURE.gz`. Building such indices for OpenWrt and relatives and publishing them as web service would be easy... but I doubt it'll make sense to keep these lists in a small embedded system...

Comment: I believe you're doing the right thing by amending the question to be more useful (and to get a more useful answer).

Comment: Thanks @yeti.  Your answer led me to http://ipkg.nslu2-linux.org/feeds/optware/ which led to http://ipkg.nslu2-linux.org/feeds/optware/syno-i686/cross/unstable/Packages.filelist which is equiv to what you provided but for my Synology platform.  So I guess the search for a given file is a manual one and you have to find the repo, distro by distro.   Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think package metadata include lists of files. I believe `ipkg search` is only meant to get package names for *installed* files, similarly to `rpm -qf`. You may need to provide full path of an installed file.

When looking for information about the *coreutils* package, you might want to try the following:

```
ipkg info coreutils
ipkg status coreutils
ipkg files coreutils
```

You can also see how the results differ for installed and not installed packages.

When searching of an installed package providing a specific file, you can use:

```
ipkg search /path/to/installed/file
```

As you pointed out in your edited question, you have to use *asterisk* if you don't want to specify the complete path name, for example:

```
ipkg search \*file

ipkg search '*file'
```

In my opinion, there's no information you can get for files that don't exist or haven't been installed.

You may also need to check whether you have metadata for packages downloaded at all and download them:

```
ipkg update
```

> How would I go about finding what pkg to install if I need a given program/util that is part of a larger collection but don't know what package contains it?

*ipkg* can't help you here as it doesn't have the data. I don't think your distribution has a tool like `apt-file` which would be a solution. In that case, you typically need to revert to using a websearch to get such information.

Sources:

- http://www.hpelbers.org/iliad/ipkg_usage

Disclaimer: I'm only using *opkg* on OpenWRT, which is very close to *ipkg*.

Comment: Thanks Pavel.  I know searching for coreutils makes no sense.  I was responding to your comment about why I thought it should return shred when there was no package called shred.

Comment: Sure. I made that comment before I looked up the semantics if `ipkg search`.

Comment: @JoelAZ: I removed that part from the answer.

Comment: I don't have reputation to vote your answer up but I take your answer as correct as you lead me to the solution and also you are correct that `ipkg search` is only related to installed packages.

Comment: @JoelAZ: While you don't have the power to *up* the answer, you should have the power to *accept* it as it belongs to your question.

Comment: Thanks Pavel.  Wasn't obvious but I see it now.  Still groping my way around Stack.. 8|